# Checking if a list contains None values if it contains other values, substitute by other value

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a dataset like this

| UserId | CampaignSource |
| --- | --- |
| Potato | 'hello','hello','hello',None |
| Carrot | 'hello','hello','hello',None |
| Carrot2 | None,None,None,None |
| Potato2 | 'kawai','kawai','kawai','kawai',None |

And what i want to do is basically, check if the list contains None values. And substitute every single None value by the "hello" string. But making sure, that the None filled list isnt filled.

| UserId | CampaignSource |
| --- | --- |
| Potato | 'hello','hello','hello','hello' |
| Carrot | 'hello','hello','hello','hello' |
| Carrot2 | None,None,None,None |
| Potato2 | 'kawai','kawai','kawai','kawai','kawai' |

Any takes on other ways to approach this issue? Btw couldnt display as a list bcs of weird error on stack

```
for lst in df_safe_l['CampaignSource']:
if None in lst:
    for j in set(lst):
        if j:
            lst[:] = [j] * len(lst)
```

Mine worked but i am looking for faster alternatives

Comment: So you dont want to replace `None` with `'hello'` if the list contains all `None` elements?

Comment: Yes, that is quite right

Comment: What if the list contains multiple unique words?

Comment: The list are only filled with only one word. I made sure of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try turn the list to Series and then fill the None with other values

```py
df['CampaignSource'] = df['CampaignSource'].apply(lambda lst: pd.Series(lst).bfill().ffill().tolist())
```

```
print(df)

    UserId                       CampaignSource
0   Potato         [hello, hello, hello, hello]
1   Carrot         [hello, hello, hello, hello]
2  Carrot2             [None, None, None, None]
3  Potato2  [kawai, kawai, kawai, kawai, kawai]
```

Comment: Question how i would i know which is the value i should fill it with tho? I mean i am not sure which is the unique word in each specific list. And i want to guarantee is that one

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 What do you mean by *which is the unique word in each specific list*? Does the list contain different values?

Comment: Nope in the given case, i think your solution makes sense. But i was wondering, if there was multiple values inside each list how would you do it?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 I don't understand what do you mean by saying *there was multiple values*. If it means these values are all different, it depends on **what you want to** fill in the None, by count max or something else.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the list contains only `None` by using `None in set(x) and len(set(x)) == 1`. If yes, then you don't need to replace anything. But if it contains anything other than `None` then create a new list containing the type string `len(x)` times. Try using `.apply()`. :

```
df_safe_l['CampaignSource'] = df_safe_l['CampaignSource'].apply(lambda x: x if None in set(x) and len(set(x)) == 1 else [[i for i in x if isinstance(i, str)][0]] * len(x))
```

Output:

```
    userid                       CampaignSource
0   Potato         [hello, hello, hello, hello]
1   Carrot         [hello, hello, hello, hello]
2  Carrot2             [None, None, None, None]
3  Potato2  [kawai, kawai, kawai, kawai, kawai]
```

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to mention. That the word itself of the list is not the same. The word can change, although the list only mantains one unique word